# errno 1048, 'Column 'username' cannot be null'

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Can you tell me why my code isn't working ? In my username table I have two columns, `user_id` and `username`. user_id is auto increment so I don't have that in my Sql statement, which I believe is the correct thing to do.

```
<?php
require('dbConnect.php');
$Number = $_POST['phonenumber'];

// The ? below are parameter markers used for variable binding
// auto increment does not need prepared statements
$query = "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
//bind variables

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$u);
//$stmt->bind_param("s",$u); 

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);



if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
echo 'Inserted correctly';
}

else

    {
  echo 'Error';
   echo var_dump($stmt);
    }

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I keep getting 'Error', and in my var_dump I get :

```
C:\wamp64\www\phpproject\php-project\insert.php:28:
object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => int -1
  public 'insert_id' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'param_count' => int 1
  public 'field_count' => int 0
  public 'errno' => int 1048
  public 'error' => string 'Column 'username' cannot be null' (length=32)
  public 'error_list' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'errno' => int 1048
          'sqlstate' => string '23000' (length=5)
          'error' => string 'Column 'username' cannot be null' (length=32)
  public 'sqlstate' => string '23000' (length=5)
  public 'id' => int 1
```

Comment: $u is not set, it is empty

Comment: And you're trying to execute it twice, once with prepare (good!) and once with query (bad!).

Comment: Instead of `echo 'Error';` do `echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($con);` then tell us what the error is.

Comment: and run `var_dump($_POST);` also; what shows up?

Comment: btw; your problem is here `$u` where you should have used `$Number` and error reporting would have clearly thrown you an undefined variable notice. And given that POST array isn't empty. The origin of it is unknown.

Comment: Yes, reading alright! When I put echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($con); I get : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1

Comment: then that tells me you're not using the same mysql api as the connection. Ok; I have said enough here and you have too many unknowns; the connection api and the POST array. I'm out; am sure you'll be happy about that. Take it up with the answer below.

Answer (score -2):

use null for autoincrement like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (user_id,username) VALUES (null,$username)";
```

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: actually it does make a difference, it makes it worse @Qirel and for a few reasons.

Comment: You're right, Fred! I completely overlooked the variable in the query directly, without quotes too!

Comment: Aye, agreed, a problem too common as well sadly. Although didn't bother tagging, and I'm on mobile (not the app even, using the browser),  @Fred

Comment: @Fred-ii-  you don't agreed regarding pass null for auto-increment for insert query?

Comment: @Qirel you don't agreed too?

Comment: If the ID is auto-increment, you can just leave it alone, as OP is doing, you don't have to pass null as a value. Then you introduce variables directly in the query (open for SQL-injection), and introduce a syntax error by not having quotes around strings.